# Jenkinsfile CPS Error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Below is my Jenkinsfile.

The build is proceeds normally until the end when an error is generated.

I am not familiar enough with the Scripted pipeline to know how to proceed?

My guess is I am incorrectly using the reference variable to the docker container?

By the mention of Sandbox, is it possible I am not allowed to call the stop method?

```
   node {

   checkout scm

    docker.withRegistry('http:localhost:5000') {



         try {
            stage 'Acquire HBASE Image'
            def hbase = docker.image('hbase-1.1.2').run()
            docker.image('jenkins-java').inside("--link=${hbase.id}:hbase"){




                checkout scm
                stage 'Build'
                sh 'gradle build'

                stage 'Test'
                sh 'gradle test'

                stage 'Publish Test Results'
                junit 'build/test-results/*.xml'

                stage 'Build Jar and Show Deps'
                sh 'gradle dependencies'
                sh 'gradle shadowJar'

                stage 'Integration Test'
                   withEnv(['METRICS_BATCHSIZE=10','METRICS_ZOOKEEPER_QUOROM=hbase:2181']){


                    sh 'java -jar build/libs/$(ls ./build/libs/ | grep .jar) migrate'
                    sh 'gradle integrationTest'

                   }

                stage 'Publish Integration Results'
                junit 'build/test-results/*.xml'
            }

        }
        finally {

            hbase.stop()

        }
}

}
```

The error is

```
Could not update commit status, please check if your scan credentials    belong to a member of the organization or a collaborator of the repository and repo:status scope is selected

 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hbase for class: groovy.lang.Binding
Possible solutions: class
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at      org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:46)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.withRegistry(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was clear when I began to think about the file as a programming language construct.

The solution was to declare

```
def hbase = docker.image('hbase-1.1.2').run()
```

prior to the start of the try/finally block so that the variable would be declared and in-scope of the finally block.